# Using GetObject with file argument produces Error 432: File name or class name not found during Automation

Tags: windows, vb6, attachmate-extra

I have a screen scrapping application which is in VB6, It is running on windows server 2003 and now we wanted to upgrade to windows server 2012 64 bit.

I have a problem running the below code, it gives:

> Error 432: File name or class name not found during Automation
>   operation

([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/filename-or-class-name-not-found-during-automation-operation-error-432))

```
GetObject("E:\Robots\Sessions\session1.edp")
```

I also tried specifying the class name

```
GetObject("E:\Robots\Sessions\session1.edp","Extra.system")
```

Also tried `CreateObject` first and then `GetObject`, none of them seems to be working.

Thanks,
Remya

Comment: Is your file & path valid? Is it associated with the appropriate application?

Comment: yes, I have attachmate extra  installed on my system. Also the path is correct

Comment: I wonder if there is a 32-but / 64-bit conflict here. If the "Extra.system" object is provided by a DLL then it must be a 32-bit DLL (at least, without adding some extra configuration). But if it is provided by an EXE that should not be a problem even if the EXE is 64-bit

Comment: It would be helpful to know whether or not the "session1.edp" file is a valid COM object.